# Weak-*-convergence of sin(x-hz)

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, limits, weak-convergence

I was reading the following [paper](http://scholar.google.de/scholar_url?url=https://www.aimsciences.org/article/exportPdf%3Fid%3D2075d37d-29f5-44cc-991a-b5afa2cbb906&hl=de&sa=X&ei=qGaNX5DJEoSgmwHYlJXQBQ&scisig=AAGBfm0LnCj7V5DqT-wDj2oBodCED6umOg&nossl=1&oi=scholarr) on homogenisation of optimal control problems and I was trying to understand the example given on page 419.

To get the example the authors are studying the sequence $b_h:=sin(x-hz) \in L^\infty(\Omega \times \Omega)$.

In a first step the autors calculate $b_h=sin(x-hz)=sin(x)cos(hz)+cos(x)sin(hz)$. Am I wrong on this or has it to be a minus in this formula?

In a next step they say that $b_h$ is weakly-*-converging: $$b_h \xrightarrow{w^*} 0.$$

I was trying to make the calculatiosn myself and failed. Here my ansatz:
Let $f(x,z)\in L^1(\Omega \times \Omega)$ arbitrary but fixed. To show:
$$
\int_\Omega \int_\Omega b_h(x,z)f(x,z)\, dx dz \to \int_\Omega \int_\Omega 0 f(x,z)\, dx dz = 0.
$$
So the task is to calculate
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\int_\Omega \int_\Omega (sin(x)cos(hz)-cos(x)sin(hz))f(x,z)\, dx dz
$$
My first attempt was just to put the limes into the integral but I am not allowed to do this in this case. Whats the next step to calculate the limit? Is it via step functions and their density?

Comment: 1)Yes, there has to be a minus.